# Omnet runs out of memory after 3 second of runtime?

Tags: c++, memory-management, omnet++

I have created a network for some experiments and using 64 Hosts and sending in traffic through 48 hosts, after running for 3 seconds it consumes all memory and kicks kswapd0 process and then the simulation becomes extremely slow. Can anyone help with how to resolve this?

I tried debugging for memory leak with valgrind and it is showing issue in below code.

Note: I am deleting packet after rounting when it reaches end.

I tried different packet size in configuration but issue without related to packet size, so I focused on header and it matches the valgrind result.

Second line with "auto" keyword.

```
if (vlanTag) {
    auto vlanHeader = new inet::Ieee8021qHeader();
    vlanHeader->setPcp(vlanTag->getPcp());
    vlanHeader->setDe(vlanTag->getDe());
    vlanHeader->setVid(vlanTag->getVID());
    ethernetMacHeader->setSTag(vlanHeader);
    delete packet->removeTagIfPresent<VLANTagReq>();
    EV_INFO << getFullPath() << ":Encapsulating higher layer packet `"
                   << packet->getName() << "' into VLAN tag" << endl;
    totalEncap++;
    emit(encapPkSignal, packet);
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide [mcve]?

Comment: Found the issue with Valgrind, vlanHeader was added in packet but not deleted. So that was memory leak